# Return an array which is iniated in a one liner

Tags: c++, arrays, return-value, one-liner

I want to return an array of my custom structure object `timeInDay` with as few lines as possible, in order to return a day in my time schedule.

```cpp
struct timeInDay[] getRingTimesForWeekDay(int day) {
  switch (day) {
    case MONDAY:    return { {7, 50} };
    case TUESDAY:   return { {7, 50} };
    case WEDNESDAY: return { {7, 20} };
    case THURSDAY:  return { {7, 50} };
    case FRIDAY:    return { {7, 50} };
    case SATURDAY:  return { {7, 50} };
    case SUNDAY:    return { {7, 50} };
  }
}
struct timeInDay {
  unsigned short hour;
  unsigned short minute;
};
```

Right now it produces an error with the return value of the method:

```
error: decomposition declaration cannot be declared with type 'timeInDay'
 struct timeInDay[] getRingTimesForWeekDay(int day) {
```

Would be deeply appreciated if anybody could write down their way of doing it with as few lines as possible.

Comment: C-style arrays can not be returned from functions.  This function seems to always return a single `timeInDay`.  Why are you trying to return an **array** of these objects?

Comment: `timeInDay getRingTimesForWeekDay(int day);`

Comment: wait sorry, the outdated code gave that error. I edited the question, sorry again.

Comment: If you really need to return an array, then use `std::array<timeInDay, 1>` (where you replace `1` with the actual number of elements) or `std::vector<timeInDay>` if you don't know the number of elements.

Comment: But, as mentioned, you always seem to return only one element so why not return it as an object? Why do you need to return an "array"? What problem is that supposed to solve? This feels very much like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @Some-programmer-dude uhm well actually thanks a lot for mentioning the XY problem, I made my code so that I maybe in the future could add another ring time, but now I think of it, this is unlikely. And if I do I will be a better c++ programmer, haha. Should I delete my question now?

Comment: @obe Why delete it? Future readers may find this post and use it.

Comment: @digito_evo people might try to answer it unnecessarily. What's more important, answering my question or someone's question which is actually useful?

Comment: @obe Every question is useful to some extent. Yours is useful since it is usually a beginner's mistake in C++. Coupled with a good answer it will become a nice asset for future learners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No line is required to return a c-array from a function, because you cannot return a c-array from a function.

You could dynamically allocate it and return a pointer to first element and size, but you better stay away from that in favor of `std::array`:

```
#include <array>

struct timeInDay {
  unsigned short hour;
  unsigned short minute;
};

std::array<timeInDay,1> getRingTimesForWeekDay(int day) {
  switch (day) {
    case 1:    return { {7, 50} };
    default:   return { {7, 50} };
  }
}
```

However, as others have mentioned already, the function does only return a single element, so it isnt clear why you want an array in the first place.

PS: If the size of the array is dynamic, use `std::vector`

Comment: In fact, C arrays can be returned. You just need to make a new struct and declare the array there and then return an instance of that struct. You can even return multiple C arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Your `getRingTimesForWeekDay` just returns a `timeInDay` struct object. If you want to have an array of `timeInDay` structs, you can just define it:

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/Me3KPh3aq)

```cpp
    std::array<timeInDay, num_week_days> ringTimesForWeekDays{
        {{7, 50}, {7, 50}, {7, 20}, {7, 50}, {7, 50}, {7, 50}, {7, 50}}
    };
```

If you want to be able to regenerate the contents of the array by code later on, you can keep the `getRingTimesForWeekDay` function, and use it to fill the array:

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/bYEdejja1)

```cpp
    std::generate(std::begin(ringTimesForWeekDays), std::end(ringTimesForWeekDays),
        [d = DayOfWeek::MONDAY]() mutable {
            auto t{ getRingTimesForWeekDay(d) };
            d = static_cast<DayOfWeek>(static_cast<int>(d) + 1);
            return t;
        });
```

Also, you could initialize your array at compile time with the results of an immediately invoked lambda expression:

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/KGoq7vqeY)

```cpp
    constexpr auto ringTimesForWeekDays{
        [](){
            std::array<timeInDay, num_week_days> result{};

            std::generate(std::begin(result), std::end(result), [d = DayOfWeek::MONDAY]() mutable {
                    auto t{ getRingTimesForWeekDay(d) };
                    d = static_cast<DayOfWeek>(static_cast<int>(d) + 1);
                    return t;
                });

            return result;
        }()
    };
```